# Regular Expression - isMediaFile

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to do a medio file checking, But it is failing,

It is giving false:

My Expression:

```
MEDIA_PATTERN = "([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(aif|iff|m3u|m4a|mid|mp3|mpa|wav|wma|3g2|3gp|asf|avi|flv|m4v|mov|mp4|mpg|rm|srt|swf|vob|wmv|3d))$)";
```

I changed to

MEDIA_PATTERN = "([^.*]+(\.(?i)(m3u|m4a|mp3|mpa|mkv|wav|avi|flv|m4v|mov|mp4|vob))$)";

It working but It still not working if the file name is like this:

```
System.out.println(isMediaFile("Chaplin.1992.720p.BrRip.x264.YIFY.mp4"));
```

My Sample File Name:

```
public static void isMediaFileTest(){
        System.out.println(isMediaFile("Electrifying Bhupalam Thillana - Sridevi Nrithyalaya - Bharathanatyam Dance.mp4"));
        System.out.println(isMediaFile("Electrifying Bhupalam Thillana Sridevi Nrithyalaya Bharathanatyam Dance.mp4"));

    }




 public static boolean isMediaFile(String str)
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Constants.MEDIA_PATTERN);
        if (str == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return p.matcher(str).matches();
    }
```

What is the wrong.

Comment: `[^\s]+`  = `\S` only matches non-whitespace chars, replace it with `.*`

Comment: Or don't bother matching more than you need : just make sure the extension is correct but don't try to match the rest of the filename, e.g. `\\.(aif|iff|...|wmv|3d)$`

Comment: By the way, your Pattern is constant, so there's no need to compile it every single time you call isMediaFile. Just put it into Constants.

Comment: @Aaron , you are right, I removed rare once. It is working fine. But It not working if the file contains multiple dots.

Comment: @Sun I should have mentioned that with the regex I provided you shouldn't use `Matcher.matches()` which tries to match the whole string with the pattern but rather `Matcher.find()` which will either find the extension at the end of the filename and return true or return false if the extension doesn't match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define the `MEDIA_PATTERN` like

```
MEDIA_PATTERN = "(?i).*\\.(?:aif|iff|m3u|m4a|mid|mp3|mpa|wav|wma|3g2|3gp|asf|avi|flv|m4v|mov|mp4|mpg|rm|srt|swf|vob|wmv|3d)"
```

where

- `[^\s]+` (equal to `\S+` and matching only one or more non-whitespace chars) is replaced with `.*` that matches 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (`.*` is necessary as the regex is used with `Matcher#matches()` method that requires a full string match)
- `$` removed since it is redundant (due to the use in `.matches()` method)
- Some redundant capturing groups are also removed
- `(?i)` is better placed at the start of the pattern here, it should modify the whole pattern anyway.

You should also declare the `Pattern` outside the method where it is used for better performance (see [@k314159's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825576/regular-expression-ismediafile/63825954#comment112864359_63825576)),

```
public static Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Constants.MEDIA_PATTERN);
public static boolean isMediaFile(String str)
{
    if (str == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return p.matcher(str).matches();
}
```

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/0AZdPB).